# How to add subquestion statements in a cloze question using R/exams

Tags: moodle, r-exams

I need a `cloze` question with a general statement and some results (random data and tables of statistical analysis) that includes several `schoice` questions each of them with its own statement. But I don't know how I should include that subquestions statements. A simple example **cloze0.Rmd** is shown below. I need export 30 different versios of this `cloze` question  to `moodle` using the command `exams2moodle("cloze0.Rmd", n = 30, name = "Simple_Cloze0", rule = 'none', schoice = list(shuffle = T), verbose = T)` but this command includes the fist subquestion statement as a response option and misplace the correct answer in all subquestions. Any ideas much appreciated!

**cloze0.Rmd** ==> ([**moodle-result**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zfJXSEZuaLpo9t3jNAjrCQK2ROzqpPrf/view?usp=sharing)) ==> ([**needed-moodle-result**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XNwoNarb8EkSDvflNQI2RFZ7U-okkX-H/view?usp=sharing))

````
```{r data generation, echo = FALSE, results = "hide"}
# sample
dt <- rnorm(30, 100, 5)

# Statistics
ndt <- length(dt)
mdt <- mean(dt)
sdt <- sd(dt)
vdt <- var(dt)
cvdt <- sdt/abs(mdt)
```                              

Question
========
A sample of **`r ndt`** individuals is draw and a variable $X$ is measured.

```{r, echo = F, comment = NA}
dt
```

Answerlist
----------
Choose the mean of $X$.
* `r mdt`.
* `r sdt`.
* `r vdt`.
* `r cvdt`.

Choose the standard deviation of $X$.
* `r mdt`.
* `r sdt`.
* `r vdt`.
* `r cvdt`.

Choose the variance of $X$.
* `r mdt`.
* `r sdt`.
* `r vdt`.
* `r cvdt`.

Choose the coefficient of variation of $X$.
* `r mdt`.
* `r sdt`.
* `r vdt`.
* `r cvdt`.

Meta-information
================
exname: simple_cloze
extype: cloze
exsolution: 1000|0100|0010|0001
exclozetype: schoice|schoice|schoice|schoice
extol: 0|0|0|0
exshuffle: TRUE
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this kind of control over the formatting of a cloze exercise then it is better to use `##ANSWERi##` syntax or placing the answer interaction fields where you need them. See the [boxhist2](http://www.R-exams.org/templates/boxhist2/) exercise for a worked example.

In your case I would put the following questions before the `Answerlist`:

```
a. Choose the mean of $X$: ##ANSWER1##
b. Choose the standard deviation of $X$: ##ANSWER2##
c. Choose the variance of $X$: ##ANSWER3##
d. Choose the coefficient of variation of $X$: ##ANSWER4##
```

And then the `Answerlist` would just look like this:

```
Answerlist
----------
* `r mdt`.
* `r sdt`.
* `r vdt`.
* `r cvdt`.
* `r mdt`.
* `r sdt`.
...
```

Note that rather than manually listing all four statistics four times you could also do the following to create the entire `Answerlist`:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, results="asis"}
answerlist(rep(c(mdt, sdt, vdt, cvdt), 4), markup = "markdown")
```
````

I would also add some rounding to, say, three digits for the answers. (Well, personally, I would create a cloze with four "num" items rather than "schoice" items.)

By default

```
exams2moodle("cloze0.Rmw")
```

will create dropdown menus for each of the four choice list (display `"MULTICHOICE"` in Moodle). If you really want radio buttons in a vertical layout instead (display `"MULTICHOICE_V"`) you can switch to:

```
exams2moodle("cloze0.Rmd",
  cloze = list(cloze_schoice_display = "MULTICHOICE_V"))
```

Note that in versions up to 2.3-6 of the package, the argument was called `cloze_mchoice_display` rather than `cloze_schoice_display`.

Comment: Thank you very much. That works perfect!.